# need advice on strings/numbers Python.3x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter

So there is my code so far, idea is to count number of each characters and it works, but the tweak is I need somehow to replace number with "stars" ('*'). Let me make example so it's easier to understand.

```
entert text please.
HEY hei
```

now it is:

```
histogram:
e: 2
h: 2
i: 1
y: 1
```

wanted:

```
histogram:
e: **
h: **
i: *
y: *
```

And for some one wondering, yes this is part of school assignment and I don't want to use Collection / counter

```
def count_dict(mystring):
    d = {}
    # count occurances of character
    for w in mystring:
        d[w] = mystring.count(w)
    # print the result
    print("histogram:")
    for k in sorted(d):
        (str(d[k])).replace(isdigit(), '*')
        print (k +': ' + str(d[k]))

mystring = input("entert text please.\n").lower().replace(' ', '')

count_dict(mystring)
```

**Solved**

**EDIT:**

this little trick did the work:

```
m = int(str(d[k]))
        print (k +': ' + m*'*')
```

Comment: Do you know that `print('!' * 3)` prints '!!!'

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Had to force it into int --> m = int(str(d[k])) and then print(m*'*')

Comment: `d[k]` is already an int. so `m=d[k]` or simply using `d[k]` instead of `m` is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

```
>>> '*'*2
'**'

>>>> '*'*3
'***'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary of letter counts

```
s = 'Hello world this is my sentence'
unique_letters = filter(lambda i : i.isalpha(), set(s.lower()))
```

This is the set of unique_letters

```
['c', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'h', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 's', 'r', 't', 'w', 'y']
```

We can take advantage of the `*` operation to make the string of asterisks. This can be done in a dict comp.

```
star_dict = {i : '*' * s.count(i) for i in unique_letters}
```

`star_dict` is now

```
{'c': '*', 'e': '****', 'd': '*', 'i': '**', 'h': '*', 'm': '*', 'l': '***', 'o': '**', 'n': '**', 's': '***', 'r': '*', 't': '**', 'w': '*', 'y': '*'}
```

And to print it:

```
for key in star_dict:
    print key, ':', star_dict[key]

c : *
e : ****
d : *
i : **
h : *
m : *
l : ***
o : **
n : **
s : ***
r : *
t : **
w : *
y : *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Counter:

```
s='HEY hei'

from collections import Counter

hist=Counter(c for c in s.lower() if c.strip())
for l, c in hist.most_common():
    print('{}:{}'.format(l, '*'*c))
```

Prints:

```
e:**
h:**
i:*
y:*
```

If you cannot use Counter, you can do it the 'old fashioned way':

```
count={}
for e in (c for c in s.lower() if c.strip()):
    count[e]=count.setdefault(e, 0)+1

for k, v in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda t:-t[1]):
    print('{}:{}'.format(k, '*'*v))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for response but:
And for some one wondering, yes this is part of school assignment and I don't want to use Collection / counter

Comment: `defaultdict`? (not quite as arcane as setdefault...)

Comment: Well if he cannot use `Counter` from `collections` I suppose he probably cannot use `defaultdict` from the same module. `setdefault` is native method of `dict` since pre version 2.